# allow one location for server block otherwise return 404

Tags: nginx

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name my.example.com;

        location ~ /\.well-known/acme-challenge {
                root /var/www/html;
        }

        return 404;
}
```

I want to allow one location to be accessible on port 80 (for certbot) otherwise return 404. My code above doesn't work. If I iremove the `return 404;` line it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a root location which returns 404:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name my.example.com;

    location ~ /\.well-known/acme-challenge {
            root /var/www/html;
    }

    location / {
            return 404;
    }
```

}